# (How) can I define partial coercions in Coq?

Tags: coq

I want to set Coq up, without redefining the `:` with a notation (and without a plugin, and without replacing the standard library or redefining the constants I'm using---no cheating like that), so that I have something like a partial coercion from `option nat` to `nat`, which is defined only on `Some _`.  In particular, I want

```
Eval compute in Some 0 : nat.
```

to evaluate to `0`, and I want

```
Check None : nat.
```

to raise an error.

---

The closest I've managed is the ability to do this with two `:`s:

```
Definition dummy {A} (x : option A) := A.
Definition inverted_option {A} (x : option A)
  := match x with Some _ => A | _ => True end.
Definition invert_Some {A} (x : option A) : inverted_option x
  := match x with Some v => v | None => I end.
Coercion invert_Some : option >-> inverted_option.
Notation nat' := (inverted_option (A:=nat) (Some _)).
Eval compute in (Some 0 : nat') : nat.
Check (None : nat') : nat.
(* The term "None" has type "option ?A" while it is expected to have type
 "nat'". *)
```

However, this only works when `nat'` is a notation, and I can't define a coercion out of a notation.  (And trying to define a coercion from `inverted_option (Some _)` to `nat` violated the uniform inheritance condition.)  I thought I might be able to get around this issue by using canonical structures, but I haven't managed to figure out how to interleave canonical structure resolution with coercion insertion (see also [Can canonical structure resolution be interleaved with coercion insertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147655/can-canonical-structure-resolution-be-interleaved-with-coercion-insertion)).

(I ran into this issue when attempting to answer [Coq: Defining a subtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017560/coq-defining-a-subtype).)