# Can canonical structure resolution be interleaved with coercion insertion?

Tags: coq, coercion

In trying to solve [(How) can I define partial coercions in Coq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147643/how-can-i-define-partial-coercions-in-coq), I discovered that canonical structure resolution is not interleaved with coercion insertion:

```
Structure foo := { ty1 : Type ; ty2 : Type }.
Canonical Structure default_foo ty := {| ty1 := option ty ; ty2 := ty |}.
Definition Some_nat := @Some nat.
Coercion Some_nat : nat >-> option.
Check Some 0 : ty1 _.
Check 0 : ty1 _. (* fails *)
```

Is there a different way to invoke canonical structures or coercions such that they are interleaved?  More generally, how are canonical structure resolution and coercion insertion used in the unification / typechecking algorithm in Coq?